# Stone's theorem on one-parameter unitary groups and new self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, lie-groups, mathematical-physics

I have been following the proof of the Stone's theorem on one-parameter unitary groups.

The question is if the current list of self-adjoint operators used in quantum mechanics, including position, momentum, spin operators, **is exhaustive or not**?

Put it another way, can we say that there is no other one-parameter unitary groups, that can give us yet new self-adjoint operators, in addition to position, momentum, and spin, and therefore new observables?

I need to know if there is a **classification theorem** on one parameter unitary groups.

Do we know now that there is no other such one parameter unitary group that if exists at all then its generator will give us some yet unknown new observable in quantum theory?

Comment: No other one parameter unitary groups beyond which one?

Comment: Beyond the position, momentum, angular momentum, energy...I mean do we know all unitary groups already?

Comment: For a Hilbert space H, the group of unitaries over H, U(H) Is an infinite dimensional group. Each one parameter family of unitaries is uniquely determined by its generator (its derivative at zero). What do you want to know more? Find a basis of generators?

Comment: I just updated the question. I need to know if there is a "classification theorem" on one parameter unitary groups. Do we know now that there is no other such group that if exist at all then its generator will give us some yet unknown observable in quantum theory?

Comment: This is a question for a physicist. There is a bit of elaboration on this in the first chapter of the book "The Schrödinger Equation" of Berezin and Shubin. But ultimately, that's what they say: the choice of the operators to represent actual observables is a physical one and not a purely mathematical one.

Comment: So you confirm that a classification theorem on one parameter unitary groups doesn't exist?

Comment: The classification theorem you are looking for is Stone's theorem itself. There are as many 1-parameter groups as there are self-adjoint operators, which is to say, continuum. Also, every Borel measurable function of position also defines a self-adjoint operator. There are just loads and loads of observables other than position, momentum, spin etc.

Comment: So you can name a few one-parameter unitary groups on the Hilbert space that their generators are not associated with any currently known physical observable?

Comment: @VVM: Yes, there are operators that do not correspond to physical observables. But then again, you should ask a physicist, or look into Berezin and Shubin, where I am sure you will find some examples.